# Unable to import Firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm having trouble configuring my Angular app to connect to firebase. I've created a project on Firebase and added my app to it.

Here's my code;

> app.module.ts

```
import { initializeApp } from '@angular/fire/app';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

@NgModule({

imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    NgxPaginationModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig)
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

For some reason, the "AngularFireModule" is not recognized and as a result, all of my Imports reflect an error. The import itself up top is not displaying any errors. I'm unsure why this error is popping up so any advice in resolving this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Firebase and `@angular/fire` received breaking changes in last major release. What version of `@angular/fire` and `firebase` are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to try in this way:

```
ng add @angular/fire
```

Try to read [it](https://developers.google.com/codelabs/building-a-web-app-with-angular-and-firebase)

Answer (score 0):

Recently (end of 2021) there were major releases with breaking changes for `v9` of `firebase` package and `v7` of `@angular/fire` which introduced new modular SDK. This update should reduce the bundle size and increase bundle speed.

### [Modular SDK](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/HEAD/docs/version-7-upgrade.md#new-modular-sdk)

> In order to better support the tree-shakability introduced in Firebase
> v9 & to reduce the maintence required when the JS SDK adds new
> configuration flags, AngularFire providers now take a factory for a
> fully instantiated instance of the SDK you'd like to inject.
>
> **With old SDK**
>
> ```
> @NgModule({
>     imports: [
>         AngularFireModule.initializeApp(config),
>         AngularFirestoreModule.enablePersistence(),
>         AngularFireStorageModule,
>     ],
>     providers: [
>         { provide: USE_EMULATOR, useValue: ['localhost', 8080] },
>     ],
> })
> ```
>
> **With new SDK**
>
> ```
> @NgModule({
>     imports: [
>         provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(config)),
>         provideFirestore(() => {
>             const firestore = getFirestore();
>             connectFirestoreEmulator(firestore, 'localhost', 8080);
>             enableIndexedDbPersistence(firestore);
>             return firestore;
>         }),
>         provideStorage(() => getStorage()),
>     ],
> })
> ```

### [Compatibility mode](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/HEAD/docs/version-7-upgrade.md#compatibility-mode)

> AngularFire v7.0 has a compatibility layer that supports the
> AngularFire v6.0 API. Just change your imports from @angular/fire/* to
> @angular/fire/compat/* and firebase/* to firebase/compat/*.
>
> While not as tree-shakable as the new modular SDK, this allows you to
> upgrade and take advantage of the benefits of the new SDK ASAP.

### How to upgrade

[Here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/HEAD/docs/version-7-upgrade.md) you can check what changed in `AngularFire v7`

[Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade) you can check what changed in `Firebase v9`